# Developer Error while logging in with google in react-native + firebase

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am trying to log in with google in my project build in react-native. I am testing it on a real android device. But it is giving DEVELOPER ERROR while signing in. I have added the SHA 1 certificate of the `debug.keystore` formed in `android/app` directory of the project to the project setting in firebase console.

ERROR:

[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWi5R.png)

The following is how I am implementing it.

```
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';


const GoogleLogin = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: '************************', // From Firebase Console Settings
    });

  }, [])


  async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
    console.log('i am running on google login function')
    // Get the users ID token
    const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    console.log('idToken :', idToken)

    // Create a Google credential with the token
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }

  const handleSignIn = () => {
    onGoogleButtonPress()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Signed in with google.')
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('error while signing in with Google:', err))
  }

  return (
    <Button
      title="Google Sign-In"
      onPress={handleSignIn}
    />
  )


}
```

In `handleSignIn` method, it is going in `.catch`.

**Any help is appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

Try also passing in the accessToken.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#credential.

> At least one of ID token and access token is required.

```
 async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
    console.log('i am running on google login function')
    // Get the users ID token
    const { idToken, accessToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    console.log('idToken :', idToken, 'accessToken :', accessToken)

    // Create a Google credential with the token
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);

    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  }
```